# Securely creating a new PostgreSQL user

Tags: postgresql, psql, createuser

I'm learning the ins and outs of web development and deployment in particular.

I have a Ubuntu server, I have a unix user `userX` and I have PostgreSQL installed. I have a simple Python / Flask web application that will be ran under the `userX` unix account.

I need the web application to be able to connect to PostgreSQL so I run `sudo -u postgres createuser userX` and this returns with no errors. I can now connect to PostgreSQL using `sudo -u userX psql`.

Questions:

1. The newly created userX account (role, in PostgreSQL) does not
   require a password. On one hand, this seems correct because any password would have to be stored on the server itself if the web application required it to connect to PostgreSQL. On the other hand, not requiring a password seems insecure (although, if nobody can log in as `userX`, this should be fine)?
2. The `postgres` PostgreSQL account also did not require a password. Does this mean the `postgres` account is insecure? Should this be allowed to exist or should the `postgres` user be removed? Should I be using the `postgres` user to connect to the database instead of `userX`?
3. Where does pg_hba.conf come in to play in all of this?

Answer (score 0):

You should read about [pg_hba.conf](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html), and maybe about [SSL certificates](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-methods.html#AUTH-CERT).